# Delete photo thumbnail in Gallery after manually delete the photo file

Tags: android, image, gallery, photo, delete-file

```
case R.id.menu_delete:
    File photoToDelete = new File(photoPath, photoList[gPosition]);
    photoToDelete.delete();
    checkPhotoFolder();
    galleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("position", "" + gPosition);
    return true;
```

I'm manually delete a photo file using above code. But in the system gallery the photo still show the blank thumbnail.
The question is how can I delete the photo file and also the thumbnail of it in the gallery?

Comment: Sorry about latest answer but I did solve this error like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37855889/1332870)

Answer (score 0):

Try invoke the MediaScanner to refresh the gallery

```
// Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
// immediately available to the user.
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
        new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
    }
});
```

Code from [Google's example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: this work only for saving new photo but when it scan a deleted file it show a blank thumbnail in the system gallery.

Comment: @chengsokdara you are right I am facing with same issue. did you get any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.fromFile(photoToDelete), null, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must update the data structure (eg. list or array) that stores the photos. 
I guess it is `photoList`.
So you should do (assuming `photoList` is an array):

```
photoList = photoList.asList().remove(gPosition).toArray();
```

Comment: i mean remove the photo thumbnail in the Android built-in gallery bro.

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the question.