# When saving bitmap, I get 3 copies

Tags: java, android

I have a Save button for imageView bitmap picture. When I click it, I get 3 copies of the same image, but 2 of them are 0 bytes. Here's the image:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
public class Photo_gallery extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button save;
    ImageView slika;


    final File myDir = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/sexyImages");
    boolean success = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.photo_gallery);

        InitializeVars();

    }

    private void InitializeVars() {

        slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);


        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";

                myDir.mkdirs();

                File image = new File(myDir, fname);

                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) slika.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

                // Encode the file as a PNG image.
                FileOutputStream outStream;
                try {

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
                    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success at /sdcard/Pictures/sexyImages",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

And second queston....How to refresh the gallery app? I know I have to implement this code somewhere, but I don't know how:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: What are you talking about???

Comment: For refreshing gallery, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13532394/763459

Comment: And, could you set a break point or probably log output to make sure how many times the `onClick` is getting called? According to your code, it's somehow being called 3 times.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @vikram Well, I am saving image that is currently on the screen. But somehow it gets saved 3 times.

Comment: If the image DOES get saved 3 times, why are the `Timestamps` on the images in the screenshot 34 minutes apart?

Comment: Well I don't know that either.

Comment: Ok, delete all files from `/sdcard/Pictures/sexyImages`(consider using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) and try running your code once. Do you still get three files?